# how to conf git proxy when clone from google source

Tags: git, google-source-repositories

My target:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/brillo/manifest
```

My error report:

```
Cloning into 'manifest'... fatal: unable to access
'https://android.googlesource.com/brillo/manifest/': Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

My git config:

```
http.proxy=47.90.51.178:31702
http.https://android.googlesource.com.sslverify=false
http.https://android.googlesource.com.proxy=47.90.51.178:31702
```

for work with google git , I have edit .gitcookies followed the [official doc here](https://www.googlesource.com/new-password?state=android&code=4/AADgwJ7-bjsoSxsR1CZcUaT157wYxEYINWk4wjMp-FXflhNSlmT1BuOYluZGAyOupTImnb-19kaos23mptPcGpg#).

What's the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions do not include an http proxy.

Unless you actually need that proxy, only the http.cookiefile  should be enough, since the instructions are:

```
git config --global http.cookiefile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitcookies"
powershell -noprofile -nologo -command Write-Output ".googlesource.com`tTRUE`t/`tTRUE`txxyyzz`to`tgit-you.gmail.com=1/XX-YY-ZZ" >>"%USERPROFILE%\.gitcookies"
```

Comment: Yes,I have configed the http.cookiefile,but when clone command run ,it retruns 443 cannot connect error.So I begin to focus on http.proxy setting.

Comment: @Eilir Are you usually behind a proxy for accessing any other URL on the internet?

Comment: yes.I use vpn all the time.So you can see my question here.

Comment: here my .googlecookies :`android.googlesource.com        FALSE   /       TRUE    2147483647      o       git-myemail.com=1/Jirewysomesecletters
 android-review.googlesource.com FALSE   /       TRUE    2147483647      o       git-myemail.com=1/Jirewysomesecletters
 android.googlesource.com        FALSE   /       TRUE    2147483647      o       git-myemail.com=1/Jirewysomesecletters
 android-review.googlesource.com FALSE   /       TRUE    2147483647      o       git-myemail.com=1/Jirewysomesecletters`

Comment: @Eilir for testing, could you set https.proxy as well? (Even though you have desactivated ssl for Android)

Comment: @Eilir What is your OS and Git version?

Comment: MacOS(Darwin) git version 2.16.2

Comment: @Eilir OK, because `%USERPROFILE%` is windows-specific: you might need to adapt that setting to mac, using for instance `${HOME}`

Comment: my .gitcookies file link is ok.`http.cookiefile=/Users/me/.gitcookies`